# PHPUnit not asserting Exceptions

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5

I am using phpunit 4.8.23 with laravel 5.2.

One of my controller is throwing an HttpException as below.

```
throw new HttpException(403, 'auth_failure');
```

and in Handler.php

```
if ($e instanceof HttpException){
    return response()->json(array(...), $e->getStatusCode());
}
```

For testing this, I used the following codes in my test file.

1

```
/**
 * @expectedException Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
 * @expectedExceptionMessage auth_failure
 */
  public function testMethod(){....}
```

2

```
public function testMethod(){
$this->json(.....);
$this->setExpectedException('HttpException');
}
```

3 and even try catch

```
try {$this->json(....)}
catch(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException $e){..}
```

I tried the 3rd case with `\Exception` also.

In all cases, I get output as

```
PHPUnit 4.8.23 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException {#986
-statusCode: 403
-headers: []
#message: "auth_failure"
#code: 0
#file: "<path to file>"
#line: 103
-trace: {
57. App\Http\Controllers\DeviceController->register() ==> new    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException(): {.....
```

I have gone throgh [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159002/phpunit-doesnt-catch-expected-exceptions), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207807/phpunit-testing-exceptions-for-laravel-resource-controllers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555299/handling-laravel-httpexception-in-unit-testing) questions but could not make any progress.

**EDIT**
I hope I have provided all the relevant informations. Here is the full method anyway

```
/**
 * @expectedException Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
 * @expectedExceptionMessage auth_failure
 */
public function testRegAuthFailure()
{

    $this->json('POST',
                'auth',
                [
                    "lang" => "us_en",
                    "data" => [
                        "identity"      => "00000004",
                        "password"      => "wrong",              
                    ]
                ]
    );

    $this->setExpectedException('HttpException');
}
```

any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Could you please post the actual code that you are trying to run (i.e. full code of your test `testMethod`)?

Comment: here is the actual code

Comment: Have you tried to throw exception directly inside the "testRegAuthFailure" ?

Comment: That works, ie `thow new HttpException(403, 'auth_failure');` instead of json method call.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed up unit testing with functional testing. When you run functional tests you need to test actual output such as headers and html/json/whatever content that you will see in the browser if you make POST request to your '/user' API method.

For puse unit testing you need to create Controller and run its methods directly, for example

```
class ControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @expectedException Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
     * @expectedExceptionMessage auth_failure
     */
    public function testSomeMethod() {
        $controller = new Controller(/* mocked dependencies */);
        $controller->yourMethod();
    }

}
```

On the other hand for functional testing I prefer to test actual responses (HTTP code and content). Also you catch HttpException in Handler.php so you can't expect any in the test. You return response - it become `$this->response` in your test

This worked for me:

```
// Handler.php
if ($e instanceof HttpException) {
    return response()->json(array($e->getMessage()), $e->getStatusCode());
}


// Test
public function testRegAuthException()
{
    $this->json('POST',
        'auth',
        [
            "lang" => "us_en",
            "data" => [
                "identity"      => "00000004",
                "password"      => "wrong",
            ]
        ]
    )->seeJson(["auth_failure"]);
    $this->assertEquals($this->response->getStatusCode(), 403);
    // OR
    // $this->assertResponseStatus(403);
}
```

P.S. If you want to expect some Exception - don't catch it in Handler.php and it will be available in test via `$result->response->exception`

Correct me if i'm wrong:) and have a nice coding!

Comment: Its a testing framework provided by laravel, Sorry i didn't mention it before. [Laravel Testing](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#testing-json-apis)

Comment: Yes, I know, and it was created for functional testing, so expect exceptions from controller is not how it should be done. Anyway, its build on top of PHPUnit so phpunit's API is available